# how to Textview Linebreak?

Tags: android

I have seen the \n used on forums before, but i thought that was for programmaticly uses only in java...
the '\n' actually works in xml too!!! hope this helps.....

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/originDesc" android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginRight="15px"

        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/widget36"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="The Bullmastiff was developed in England by gamekeepers for
protection against poachers. The foundation breeding of the
modern pure-bred was 60 per cent Mastiff and 40 per cent Bulldog.
It is a guard and companion dog, and should be loyal, obedient, and thus suitable for training."

                android:textSize="10sp">

        </TextView>

</TableRow>
```

I've got this Textview(see below), the text im putting into it auto-wraps and what not, but, the text extends off the rightside of the screen, even when flipped horizontal, the lines obviuosly extend a great deal, im expecting to be still multi-lined at that point, but still extends half words off the right of the screen.

Does anyone know how i can prevent this ? I've tried shrinkColumn="1" all the way to 30 with no changes, I've tried a couple different things ontop of that.

Comment: Can you put output as you want? I mean how many characters should be display in one line?

Comment: Is your TableRow/TableLayout inside any other ViewGroup?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood, trying to solve ur problem, Considering your Textlook and not ur whole UI.......
You can use android:layout_width="fill_parent" to fill the width of the screen and to get desired space in left, right, top and bottom u can use android:paddingTop, android:paddingLeft, android:paddingRight, android:paddingBottom and for common spacing u can use android:padding and please don't forget to see ur table row property.